# 0 coefficient in newton's interpolation

Tags: functions, polynomials, interpolation

When using Newton's interpolation formula, if I get zero as a coefficient, does it mean that I have got to the most accurate description of function (such that even if I will get more points, its coefficient will be zero too)?

thank you

Answer (score 1):

No, not by far. For example, if you have fit the points
$$ (1,0), (2,0), (3,0), (4,0), (5,0) $$
with a degree-4 polynomial, that polynomial will have all zero coefficients. But if you then add the point
$$ (6,120) $$
you get nonzero coefficients everywhere in the resulting degree-5 polynomial.

Comment: Is there a way to know for sure that I have got the right function?